# Negative Binomial Distribution.

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

What is the probability that a batsman get run from $15$ balls and no run from $25$ balls before being caught behind in the $40$th balls ? Assuming he has a half-half chance to get run from each ball .

#### My Attempt:

This is a case of negative binomial distribution

So the distributional form is :

$$P(X=k)=\binom {\alpha+k-1}{k}(1-p)^{\alpha}p^k$$

$\alpha$ is number of failures and $k$ is number of successes.

$$P(X=?)=\binom {40-1}{?}(0.5)^{40}(0.5)^?$$

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about cricket rules, but if the 40th ball has to be no run...

k = number of sucesses = 15

$\alpha$ = number of failures = 25

p = (1 - p) = .5

$P(X=15)=\binom {25 + 15 - 1}{15}(1-p)^{25}p^{15}$

$P(X=15)=\binom {39}{15}(.5)^{40}$

Comment: [Law 32.5](http://www.lords.org/mcc/laws-of-cricket/laws/law-32-caught-1/) *If the striker is dismissed Caught, runs from that delivery completed by the batsmen before the completion of the catch shall not be scored ..."* and anyway if would be very unusual to complete a run before being caught "behind", i.e. by the wicketkeeper.  A bigger problem is the use of "before" in the question.